# Java FasterXml(Jackson) Mixins and Inheritance

Tags: mixins, fasterxml

There are two simple calsses

```
public class A { private int propId; public int getPropId(){return this.propId;} }
public class B extends A {  }
```

and two mixins

```
public interface AMixin{ @JsonProperty("propIdA") int getPropId();}
public interface BMixin{ @JsonProperty("propIdB") int getPropId();}

jsonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
// register mixin
jsonObjectMapper.addMixIn(B.class, BMixin.class);
jsonObjectMapper.addMixIn(A.class, AMixin.class);
```

The following two calls get the same results:

```
jsonObjectMapper.writeValue(writer, new A()); 
jsonObjectMapper.writeValue(writer, new B());
```

but i expect *propIdA* for first and *propIdB* for second one.